# “No overload matches this call” when trying to use a Vue Component with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-component

When trying to use a child component with a TypeScript Vue Component I received the following error "No overload matches this call". I'm just posting this for others, since it's a simple mistake but googling for the error came up empty for me.

```
import {ChildComponent} from './ChildComponent.vue';
@Component({
    ChildComponent
})
export class MainComponent extends Vue {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I simply forgot that the child components used are passed as properties of **components:** and not directly to **@Component**.  Hopefully this helps others in the future.

```
import {ChildComponent} from './ChildComponent.vue';
@Component({
  components: {
    ChildComponent
  }
})
export class MainComponent extends Vue {

}
```